# What is the difference between .net 4.0 and .net 4.0.3?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Been scratching my head for a while now on why a VS 2010 Wpf application won't show a designer in Blend 2012 or Blend Expression 4.

I think I now know why. In the project it is targeting .net 4.0.3 and when I change that to target .net 4.0 I lose the designer in Blend.

I really like to use blend but not sure if I can as I am the only one on the team who wants to use it.

I am not sure if I can just target 4.0 on my machine and work on it blend but not submit that so they can continue to work on .net 4.0.3 for unknown reasons.

What did 4.0.3 really bring vs 4? I only see disadvantaged so far lol.

Comment: In answer to the title, there are a whole host of [release notes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600211), none pertain to blend however.  So, perhaps its not .Net 4.0.3 that is the problem?

Comment: Well maybe not but by changing the target brings back the designer in blend. Changing it back to .net 4.0.3 and it instantly goes away again. Also this has happened on 2 different computers(though both are windows 8.1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are the only one using Blend, use the latest version which comes with Visual Studio 2013 and see if similar happens.

Comment: Wish I could but been strictly told I have to use VS 2010

Comment: @chobo2 I fully understand. I had to convince my last contract that `Visual Studio` was an editor and not a compile platform. .Net 4 is a compile platform which `Visual Studio version X` simply uses. The nuance is that VS2012/2013 will write a 12 at the top of the solution. If one uses 201X with 2010 then you have to be aware of that before you check anything in.

Comment: What do you mean you "have to be aware of that before you check anything". Ya that's what I tried to tell them especially since 2012+ can open with out a convert(though I never tried it) but in the end it was decided to use 2010 as it was safer.

Comment: @chobo2 What I meant was that `you` can use VS2012, but just be cognizant that sometimes it opens a 2010 solution, but then writes the 2012 header information. That info is simply two numbers it ups by one; that is the only change. If you check it in, it screws up the people still using 2010. So simply uncheck out any changes to the solution when using 2010. Or manually reverse those two header numbers. Use a diff from version control to see what it is doing. As to `them` thinking its safer that is like believing the world is flat. ;-)

Comment: Werid but if I open it in 2012 will it still change the solution file. I mean sometimes you need to check in the sln file in otherwise other files might get left out of the solution and hidden. I am still not sure if going to 2013 would solve my problem and would take too long to get hold of just to try. I would need someone to take a 2010 blank project I make and see if it opens up in blend with design view.

Comment: @chobo2 If you add items into the solution (projects/files) yes it will change the solution to say its 2012 format. If you don't add any files, it still may on a save, but for me, I just never checked the solution in, if I hadn't added a file. If I had, I would manually change the version back to 2010 and then check it in.

You can open in VS2012/13 & Blend for 2012 or Blend for 2013 on your own and not change the solution file; just change the xaml file(s) in question and go back to vs2010 as you see fit.